# Remove double quotes from a json string if value type is number

Tags: javascript, json

I want to remove double quotes from a json string if the type of value is number.

sample Input String

```
 "font": {
                            "style": "normal",
                            "weight": "normal",
                            "decoration": "none",
                            "size": "15",
                            "color": "#000000"
                          }
```

Expected Output string

```
 "font": {
                            "style": "normal",
                            "weight": "normal",
                            "decoration": "none",
                            "size": 15,
                            "color": "#000000"
                          }
```

how it can done??

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i am trying to do it by using JSON.stringify with argument replacer

Comment: The [specification](http://json.org/) shows everything that can validate as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each field in your object, check if its value is a number and if so, replace it :)

```
function doIt (myThingee) {
    var keys = Object.keys(myThingee);
    var value;

    for (key in keys) {
        value = parseInt(myThingee[key], 10);

        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            myThingee[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A number is more than just the integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
 var obj = {
    "style": "normal",
        "weight": "normal",
        "decoration": "111",
        "size": "15",
        "color": "#000000"
};
var newObj = {};
for (var key in obj) {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(obj[key])) { //test for number Or use /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/ for all kind of real numbers
        newObj[key] = +obj[key];
    } else {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj))
```

`newObj` will contain the resulting object.

Comment: To catch all numbers (rather than just the positive integers), the regex needs to be changed to something like `/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?(e[-+]?\d+)?$/i`.

Answer (score 0):

Check using `Number.isNaN` with an attempted cast to a number using the `+` operator. If it returns true then do nothing. If it's false then change the value of the parameter to a cast number.

```
var arr=[{"a":"b","c":"521"}];

arr.forEach(val => {
 for(let key in val) Number.isNaN(+val[key]) || (val[key] = +val[key])
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove double quotes around digits/numbers.

```
jsonString.replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"","$1");
```

above will not work if negative numbers are present.

for negative numbers, regex will be a little complex like below. But I haven't tried it.

```
"([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)"
```